# Where are Enoch and Fitz?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Season 5 of *Agents of SHIELD* introduces us to Enoch, who physically sends most of the agents to the future.

In an effort to help the Agents he has sent to the future, he works with Fitz to provide weapons and a cryo-frozen Fitz hidden in the Lighthouse.

In the future, Enoch works with the restored Fitz to help rescue the agents and send them back to the present.

While

> Enoch doesn't survive the mission to return home,

Fitz is sent back with the rest of the team.

While we're not told exactly when they've returned to, it appears to be some time after their disappearance. The agents meet the second Chronicom, Noah, but Enoch does not seem to be present.

In the present day, even though future-Enoch wasn't sent back in time, present-Enoch should still be around somewhere, and there should be a cryo-frozen Fitz in the Lighthouse.

While Hale may not believe Coulson's story about time-travel, meeting Enoch may help convince her.

### Has there been any explanation in-universe or in an interview explaining the absence of Enoch or the lack of mention of the frozen Fitz?

Comment: I have a better question. *Why* are Enoch and Fitz?!

Answer (score 6):

## They were on Enoch's ship orbiting a nearby planet.

---

I guess this is cleared at the end of Episode 5: Rewind. Hunter parts from Enoch and Leopold, and Leopold enters the cryo-sleep. In the end, you see this:

[image]

> Enoch: Good morning, Fitz. Rise and shine.
>
> Fitz:  Aah.
>
> Enoch: While you were asleep, I had time to put a plan in motion.
>   We have a few days before we arrive at the Lighthouse.
>   That should give me enough time to prepare you.
>
> Fitz: Prepare me for what?
>
> Enoch: For facing off against some of the most ruthless and brutal mobsters, monsters, and mercenaries in the galaxy.
>   I hope you have it in you.
>
> Fitz: I have it in me.

So it is indicated that Fitz (in cryo-sleep) and Enoch were in Enoch's ship orbiting a planet in our solar system.

***PS:*** The distance says 365 million mile from the Lighthouse (or, vaguely, Earth). And according to [here](https://www.space.com/18383-how-far-away-is-jupiter.html),

> *When the two planets [Earth and Jupiter] are at their closest point, the distance to Jupiter is only 365 million miles.*

So, one assumption is that Jupiter is the most likely planet around which Enoch's ship orbited till the time came.

Comment: This explains where they are 74 years in the future, but not where they are in the *present*.

Comment: I think it is implied that they were in orbit of Jupiter for the entire 74 years. So that's where they are now. It is possible they will return before the end of this season.

Comment: @phantom42 I guess they were away from Earth to be safe from the destruction of Earth (although this was quite far in the future) and primarily to stay incognito (remember, they were being hunted by Hale and her team for the alleged murder of Talbot and Fitz escaped from a prison). It is likely the latter but in all cases it would be safer option to stay completely away from Earth and I think that's what Enoch and Fitz did.

Comment: @Dennis_E I thought it was more implied that Enoch had spent a good chunk of those 74 years flying around the galaxy putting his plan in motion.

Comment: @OrangeDog You may be right. I saw the final episode...